# How to commit change on a file to affect more than one branch in git, but it should not affect on other files in both branches

Tags: git, version-control, repository

I have git repository and two git servers to maintain web application project

The two servers are

1. **development**
2. **production**

I want to create two branches with the names of **development and production**

1. In **development branch**, I will add some server-side scripting and **un-compiled** client-side scripting (JS)
2. In **production branch**, I will add some server-side scripting and **compiled(or minified)** client-side scripting (JS)

Server-side scripting files are same for both branch, if i made any modification on server-side scripting file it should affect on both branch,
but if i made any modification on un-compiled client-side scripting it should only affect on development branch.
I want to know is this possible, if it is possible how to do it

Comment: Don’t store generated files in version control.

Comment: OK thank you is there possible to do common file change to affect more than one branch, and the master branch has some extra files that not belong to the second one. now I decided to not use generated file in version control but I want to maintain serverside separately and client-side separately.

Comment: It sounds like you’re talking about a simple merge, but you’d have to edit your question to clarify it.

Answer (score 1):

When you need to edit source JS code switch to the **development** branch, edit and commit. Then switch to the **production** branch and merge **development** into it. Compile (minify) JS and commit minified version. Push branches to corresponding repositories.

```
git checkout development
vim code.js
git add code.js
git commit -m "Added new feature"

git checkout production
git merge development
js-minify code.js
git add code.js.minified
git commit -m "Minified version"

git push devserver development
git push prodserver production
```

Comment: If i checkout between branches files of the previous branch files that not belongs to the current branch automatically deleted from the disk. It is like, if i did as you mentioned and then checkout back to the development branch some files from production branch removed from disk but i want those files even though i switch between branches.

Comment: After a merge the merges commit and all branches after it will contain a combined set of files.